R: dplyr filtering inside of a function with a NULL input
What is the correct way to perform an inline conditional check for a filter which ignores a NULL input argument?
I've recently been taught about the clean method for inline conditional filtering with dplyr.  I'm now interested in applying that to a function where one or more inputs may be NULL.  If the argument is provided, then you should filter based on that argument, but if it is null, you should not.  In this case, data will just be iris %>% tibble().  In the past, I would do this in an unwieldy manner:
testfun <- function(data, range = NULL, spec = NULL){
  if(!is.null(range)) {
    data %<>% filter(between(Petal.Length, range[1], range[2]))
  }
  
  if(!is.null(spec)) {
    data %<>% filter(Species %in% spec)
  }
  
  return(data)
}

My attempt at inline conditional checks looks like this
testfun <- function(data, range = NULL, spec = NULL){
  data %>%
    filter(
      if(!is.null(range)) {between(Petal.Length, range[1], range[2])},
      if(!is.null(spec)) {Species %in% spec},
    )
}

This works as long as I provide inputs for range and spec.  However, if I leave one of them null, I get an error message such as:

Error in 'filter()':
ℹ In argument: 'if (...) NULL'.
Caused by error:
! '..2' must be of size 150 or 1, not size 0.


You can't pass NULL to filter() so just add an ... else TRUE to your condition statements.

@lroha Brilliant!  You are correct, "... range[2])} else TRUE," works.  If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it as the correct one.  Thanks!

User lroha commented on the post with what I believe to be the correct answer, but they have posted it as an answer.

You can't pass NULL to filter() so just add an ... else TRUE to your condition statements.

So, instead of:
testfun <- function(data, range = NULL, spec = NULL){
  data %>%
    filter(
      if(!is.null(range)) {between(Petal.Length, range[1], range[2])},
      if(!is.null(spec)) {Species %in% spec},
    )
}

It should be:
testfun <- function(data, range = NULL, spec = NULL){
  data %>%
    filter(
      if(!is.null(range)) {between(Petal.Length, range[1], range[2])} else TRUE,
      if(!is.null(spec)) {Species %in% spec} else TRUE,
    )
}


Set the defaults in the argument list to values that would cause the filter expressions to evaluate to TRUE
testfun2 <- function(data, range = c(-Inf, Inf), spec = data$Species) {
 data %>%
    filter(
      between(Petal.Length, range[1], range[2]),
      Species %in% spec
    )
}

or keep them as NULL in the argument list but then reset them in the code
testfun3 <- function(data, range = NULL, spec = NULL) {
  range <- range %||% c(Inf, Inf)
  spec <- spec %||% data$Species
  data %>%
    filter(
      between(Petal.Length, range[1], range[2]),
      Species %in% spec
    )
}

Another possibility is to incorporate the NULL check in the conditions
testfun4 <- function(data, range = NA, spec = NA) {
  data %>%
    filter(
      is.na(range) | between(Petal.Length, range[1], range[2]),
      is.na(spec) | Species %in% spec
    )
}


While these are notable workarounds, I still prefer the method that lroha provided in their comment on the original post.

One could argue that adding if statements to work around using the wrong defaults is the problem and even if we decide to keep NULL defaults sticking if statements in the filter when one could simply add additional conditions to the filter (see third approach in answer for a resolution) is a problem.

I wouldn't say that NULL is the wrong default.  I have very large data sets, and choosing to not filter is faster than performing a filter which accepts all records.  I must confess that I'm having trouble with your third approach (testfun4), as it errors out when no range argument is provided.  I'm not saying that your answer is bad, just that Iroha's fix is preferable given the situation I have.

I had tested testfun4on R 4.0.3/dplyr 1.0.2 and there it did not generate any errors but I have now tested it on R 4.4.1/dplyr 1.1.4 and it seems the dplyr code for between has been completely rewritten (likely in dplyr 1.1) and in that version does generate an error when passed NULL so we have changed NULLs to NAs in testfun4 and it now works again. Thank you for pointing out problem. At any rate note it is not true that the if in 2nd (last) version of testfun in question avoids using filter for NULL arguments. If that were important only first version in question does that.
